# Arithmetic Precedence

Tags: arithmetic, trigonometry

I stumbled upon an answer in another Stack Exchange site which is :

> $x = cx + r \times \cos a$
>
> $y = cy + r \times \sin a$
>
> With the above example, a degree of 76 would be:
>
> $x = 115 + 110 \times \cos 76$
>
> $y = 115 + 110 \times \sin 76$
>
> Which gives us 205.676, 177.272

I've been wondering why are $x = 205.676$ and $y = 177.272$ ?

Shouldn't those are $x = 141.611$ and $y = 221.732$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of you is using sine and cosine functions designed for degrees and the other is using functions designed for radians.

If the angle $a= 76$ is being measured in degrees than $141.611$ and $221.732$ are correct results of the calculations.  The same angle in radians is about $1.32645$.

Comment: Umm.. So what are the values for sin 76 and cos 76 in radian function? I'm sorry, but I can't seem to find 'em on my calculator

Comment: Never mind. I found 'em already. Thanks